# If is(':hover') animate background color not working

Tags: jquery

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I just want to fade the background color of a button (id of "menu-button") on hover.

JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 if($('menu-button').is(':hover')) {
    $( this ).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#666"
 })} else {
    $( this ).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#FFF"
 })};

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `.on()`

```
$("#menu-button").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#666"});
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFF"});
    }
});
```

Alternatively, this can also be done with pure CSS3

```
#menu-button {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#menu-button:hover {
    background-color: #666;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

Comment: +1. In this example, your hooking the animation onto the mouse enter and mouse leave event. If it's just changing colours and adding no further functionality I would use pure CSS3 (An improvement would be to include the transition properties on the normal #menu-button selector styles to get the animation on when your stop hovering over the button.) Just for further clarification, OP's code is only checking if #menu-button has hover state when the JS is run rather than hooking into the event listener.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.menu-button').hover( function() {
        $( this ).animate({ backgroundColor: "#666" });
    }, function(){
        $( this ).animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFF" });
    });
});
```